# Excel Custom Sorting for alphanumeric data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data in Excel file:

```
Brandon 1
Brandon 10
Brandon 11
Brandon 2
Brandon 3
Brandon 4
John 1
John 2
John 20
John 21
John 22 
John 3
John 4
```

I want to sort it by Name first and then the number:

```
Brandon 1
Brandon 2
Brandon 3
Brandon 4
Brandon 10
Brandon 11
John 1
John 2
John 3
John 4 
John 20
John 21
John 22
```

Any suggestions? I don't want to add leading zeros to numbers.

Comment: Have you *tried* sorting?

Comment: Whether you use the Data:Sort or you sort using the filters, the key is to sort the numbers first, then the names.  Concerning your statement about leading zeros, that does not matter to the sort actions unless your numbers are stored as text.

Comment: Are the numbers in a **separate column**?

Comment: @ReyJuna Expanding the sample set, if I try sorting considering data as Text field I will get results like:
Brandon 1
Brandon 10
Brandon 11
Brandon 2
Brandon 3
Brandon 4
John 1
John 2
John 20
John 21
John 22
.
.
.
John 3
John 4

This is not the desirable answer. I am looking for a solution where
I can sort the data
Brandon 1
Brandon 2
.
.
.
.
Brandon 10
Brandon 11
.... and so on

Comment: The data is in single row @Gary'sStudent

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Yes, tried sorting and custom sorting functions  in Excel

Comment: Since your data is in a single **column**, consider using `text to columns` to split it. If you then do a sort by name then number, you should get the desired result

Comment: Since you have them in one field, and that field is a text field, that is the sort order you will get.  If you use @cybernetic.nomad's solution, you still need to get the number column into number format.  And you will need to sort that number field first, then the name field to get it into the order you requested.  If you can't split the field, then you will need to look at ways to pad the numbers with leading zeros or create a VBA solution.  Since you state you don't want the leading zeros, that would only leave VBA.

Comment: @KedarKulkarni, it's not a good practice that frequently you are changing sample data, since already been answered !!

Answer (score 1):

Create a second colum with the numbers. You can use a second formula to fill the column

If the numbers don't exceed 99

- A1: Brandon 1
- B1: `=VALUE(RIGHT(A1;2))`

Else first find the last space

- B1: `=VALUE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))),1)))`

https://trumpexcel.com/find-characters-last-position/

Answer (score 0):

One option is:

1. Splitting your column into 2 columns.
   This can be done with:

   1.1.  *Data* -> *Text to columns* -> ...

   1.2. Formulas (my Excel is in Spanish, so I may slightly miss the names of the functions). Assuming your datum is in D1, for the name use `=LEFT(D1,FIND(" ",D1)-1)` and for the number use `=INT(RIGHT(D1,LEN(D1)-FIND(" ",D1)))` or  `=VALUE(RIGHT(D1,LEN(D1)-FIND(" ",D1)))`. Then copy down the formulas.
2. Using *Data* -> *Sort* and *Add level* to sort by the two criteria.

You can record a macro while you are doing that, to automate the process via VBA.
You can even condensate all this into a User Defined Function via VBA.

Answer (score -1):

**Your problem can be solved by using Helper Column:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- I'm assuming that Names are in `A2:A9`.
- Enter this Formula in `C2` & fill down.

  `=TEXT(A2,"###")`
- Select Range `A1:C9`.
- From **Home Tab** click on **Sort** Icon & 
  Select **Custom Sort**.
- Set Sort Order & others as shown in Screen Shot 
  below.

[image]

- Finish with **Ok**.

*You find Names in expected order.*

[image]

**Edited:**

**I'm editing since OP has got new set of Sample Data.**

- New set of Data can be Sorted in desire order, using few Helper Columns.

[image]

- Enter this Formula in `B2` & fill down.

  ```
  =VALUE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2) - MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, A2&"0123456789")) +1))
  ```
- Write this one in `C2` & fill down.

`=LEFT(A2,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A2&1234567890))-1)`

- Now select `A1:C14` & From **Home Tab** click **Sort** Command and hit **Custom Sort**.
- Set Order and Others as shown in Screen Shot below.
  [image]
- Finish with **Ok**

*You get new set of Data in desire order.*

[image]

**Note,** *Later on you may hide Helper Column.*

Comment: why do you want to use `=TEXT(A2,"###")`, what it does with these entries?

Comment: also it need to correctly work for two digit numbers

Comment: @MátéJuhász, my post was for previous values now it has been edited,, so let me find the crack point!!

Comment: @MátéJuhász, check the edited part,, now the issue has been fixed !!

Comment: Yes, this looks great now! I still don't understand however what's the benefit of using `=TEXT(A2,"###")`? Or keeping first half of your question. It just sort the original data. (`=TEXT(A2,"###")` doesn't seem to change anything).

Comment: @MátéJuhász, technically it's to convert whole into Text but it's true also that it doesn't makes any crucial difference but I've used it as abandon precaution.